# How to verify iOS Data Storage Guidelines

Tags: ios, iphone, data-storage

Our app is rejected because of following reason.

> We have also found that your app does not follow the iOS Data Storage
>   Guidelines, which is required per the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> In particular, we found that on launch and/or content download, your
>   app stores 6.1MB. To check how much data your app is storing:
>
> - Install and launch your app
> - Go to Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup > Manage Storage
> - If necessary, tap "Show all apps"
> - Check your app's storage
>
> The iOS Data Storage Guidelines indicate that only content that the
>   user creates using your app, e.g., documents, new files, edits, etc.,
>   should be backed up by iCloud.
>
> Temporary files used by your app should only be stored in the /tmp
>   directory; please remember to delete the files stored in this location
>   when the user exits the app.
>
> Data that can be recreated but must persist for proper functioning of
>   your app - or because customers expect it to be available for offline
>   use - should be marked with the "do not back up" attribute. For NSURL
>   objects, add the NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey attribute to prevent the
>   corresponding file from being backed up. For CFURLRef objects, use the
>   corresponding kCFURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey attribute.

We are storing our book's cover pages in NSDocument directory, and these are not user specific so as per iOS Data Storage Guidelines we have  used NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey attribute to prevent these files form backup. But still our app is rejected.

How we can verify that we are following ios data storage guidelines. Is there any tool provided by apple?

Comment: why not save your book's cover pages in the cache directory and not the NSDocument directory instead?

Comment: cache directory will be fine ? apple has not mentioned this in reason they told to use temp directory

Comment: yes, cache directory should be fine.  The NSDocument directory is meant for *user created* content, not extra goodies or content that your app downloads from remote sites in order to get around the cellular data size limits or intimidating app store sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Apple seems to be enforcing this more stringently with the introduction of iOS 8.

Here are the [iOS Data Storage Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/index.html), and if you cannot move it to the /Library/Caches directory, here is a [Technical Q&A](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1719/_index.html) for how to mark files so that they are not backed up.

There doesn't appear to be a way to check on the simulator, but once you push it to the device, you can follow Apple's suggestion above to verify how much space is being used:

- Install and launch your app
- Go to Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup > Manage Storage
- If necessary, tap "Show all apps"
- Check your app's storage

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no such tool.

In general, make sure to store downloaded files in the temp or cache directories, and mark them as excluded from backup - that should be enough.